# Find and Replace word in innerHTML using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to find and replace a word inside the html of a webpage using Selenium

I have tried this without success:

```
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/")
time.sleep(1)
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'power')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'example'", element)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find_element_by_xpath` instead of `find_elements_by_xpath`
So that your code will be

```
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/")
time.sleep(1)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'power')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'example'", element)
```

Also it will be better to use explicit wait instead of hardcoded sleep pause

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(),"power")]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'example'", element)
```